# How can I use Firebase on Basic4Android applications?

Tags: basic4android

I try to use the new Firebase from Google.How can I use Firebase on Basic4Android applications?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial here in the B4X forum pages:
https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/integrating-firebase-services.67692/#content

(Ignore the first line about B4A version 6 not being available.)

Regards

Joe